# Request mapping with different url but having same parameters and same method functionalities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is my sample controller method,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/unsecure/support",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<someDTO> getSupportNumber(@RequestParam(value = "countryId") Long countryId) {
    someDTO contactNos = supportService.getSupportNumbers(countryId);
    return new ResponseEntity<someDTO>(contactNos, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/support", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<someDTO> getSupportNumberSecure(@RequestParam(value = "countryId") Long countryId) {
    someDTO contactNos = supportService.getSupportNumbers(countryId);
    return new ResponseEntity<someDTO>(contactNos, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

"unsecure" is ignored by over riding configure method in spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, whereas other URL's will be authenticated.

```
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/master/unsecure/**");
```

Is there any possibility in clubbing both the methods as one, since only url changes or please share your thoughts how effectively it can be implemented.

Comment: simply keep the single method as open it will work for both authentication and without authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/unsecure/support","/support"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<someDTO> getSupportNumber(@RequestParam(value = "countryId") Long countryId) {
    someDTO contactNos = supportService.getSupportNumbers(countryId);
    return new ResponseEntity<someDTO>(contactNos, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Because the value attribute of @RequestMapping does accept multiple mappings

or

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/unsecure/support",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<someDTO> getSupportNumber(@RequestParam(value = "countryId") Long countryId) {
return getSupportNumberSecure(countryId)
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/support", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<someDTO> getSupportNumberSecure(@RequestParam(value = "countryId") Long countryId) {
someDTO contactNos = supportService.getSupportNumbers(countryId);
return new ResponseEntity<someDTO>(contactNos, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```